# Creating a dict of labels and their point objects from a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating an interactive graph where I can select the points of a scatter plot for further operations e.g. swapping positions with another point. When the point is selected, it turns black to indicate that the point has been selected.

[image: Sample interaction]

There may be several scatter plots in the figure and each plot has a unique color so to retain the original color for each point, I need to create a dictionary of labels (key) and their point objects (value). Other values in the pairing include original color, xy position, etc.

Here's a single scatter plot and it's pick event function:

```
self.scatter = self.mplwidget_layout.canvas.ax.scatter(
    y=...,
    x=...,
    color=...,
    edgecolors=...,
    picker=True
)
self.mplwidget_layout.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.select_point)

def select_point(self, event):
    if event.mouseevent.button == 1:
        facecolor = self.scatter._facecolors[event.ind,:]

        if (facecolor == np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1]])).all():
            # Look up label-object dict 
        else:
            self.scatter._facecolors[event.ind,:] = (0, 0, 0, 1)
            self.scatter._edgecolors[event.ind,:] = (1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.mplwidget_layout.canvas.draw()
```

1. It seems like I can't assign individual labels (in an array) to their points but I can map the offsets to the labels. Is there a way to give each point a name and retrieve them by name?
2. How do I access the list of point objects in a scatter plot?

Points and their assigned names:

[image: Points and their assigned names]

Comment: `scatter` returns a `PathCollection`, which as an attribute named `paths`, which in turn should contain the information about your points. If it works like the `Rect`s in a bar plot, you could just use a `dict` to do your mapping, but that would have to be tested ...

Comment: @ThomasKühn The `paths` attribute does not appear to be unique. You may try it with the sample code provided in answer below. I checked using `print(event.artist._paths)`. I guess it's because there's only one scatter plot so this might be useful in detecting which scatter plot that was clicked on.

Comment: the '_paths' are unique, I checked (by the way it's better to get them with `get_paths()`). However, if I interpret your problem correctly, you use the same co-ordinates to plot the points in each of your `subplots`. In this case each of the `_paths` objects are *equal*, but **not** *the same* (difference between `==` and `is`).

Comment: Hell, where do the `subplots` suddenly come from? This all looks a lot like a big [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are right. I was trying to use a technique that worked under a different plotting library. I will create another question with a more specific description of the problem. Apologies for the time wasted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get back the original color after clicking the point you may use the `event.ind` and the list of colors you have used initially to colorize the points. I do not see the need for a dictionary here at all.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(6)
y = np.random.rand(6)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor("k")

fcolor = plt.cm.RdYlBu(x)
ecolor = ["k"]*6

scatter = ax.scatter(x,y, s=100, facecolors=fcolor,edgecolors=ecolor , picker=True)

def select_point(event):
    if event.mouseevent.button == 1:
        facecolor = scatter._facecolors[event.ind,:]

        if (facecolor == np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1]])).all():
            scatter._facecolors[event.ind,:] = fcolor[event.ind]
            scatter._edgecolors[event.ind,:] = (0, 0, 0, 1)
        else:
            scatter._facecolors[event.ind,:] = (0, 0, 0, 1)
            scatter._edgecolors[event.ind,:] = (1, 1, 1, 1)

        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', select_point)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. If there are multiple scatter plots and I need to relocate two or more points, it would be a lot easier and straightforward if I can retrieve the point objects by name and modify them individually e.g. show/hide. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like matplotlib doesn't work that way because the points are referred to by their indices. Is there a way for `pick_event` to know which `scatter` or `PathCollection` that the point belonged to when it was clicked?

Comment: This example shows how to recreate the original color of a scatter point from one scatter plot when being clicked on, because this is how I understood the question. I'm not sure what you mean by "name", but you can surely interprete the `event.ind` as "name" if you want (the first point is named `0`, second is named `1` etc.). As always it would be "a lot easier and straightforward" if the question had the *actual*  problem in it (what are you trying to achieve? If you want to have two scatter plots, but the question has only one, it's certain that you don't get a satisfying answer).

Comment: Changing the color of the points is just an example of how I would use a dict of point objects of the entire plot. I stated the problem in the title which has nothing to do with recreating the original colors of scatter points. I appreciate your example though because I've never thought of using a colormap as a way to look up the original colors. The problem with `event.ind` is that if I have multiple scatter plots, it wouldn't work unless I can tell which `scatter` that the point that was clicked on, belong to. I figured that a dict of points and their names would solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help if the example you show has nothing to do with the problem you want to solve. If the problem involves two scatter plots, use an example with two scatter plots. If the points shall have names, create an example where there are names somewhere. Chose an example case where the names would actually matter (not color coding, where they are irrelevant).